# Preserve leading zeros using pandas to_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `pandas` DataFrame containing leading zeros. I want to export it to CSV, but the `to_csv()` method removes leading zeros from the numbers. How can I preserve them?

Comment: are these values NaN in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['leading zeros column'] = '\t' + df['leading zeros column']
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

you will get what you need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly happened to your code, but it might be a good idea to replace NaNs and then see if 0 means NaN in your case.

Comment: for example I have numbers : [012, 56, 12, 98, 045] i save it with to_csv and hen i open my Excel numbers are: 12, 56, 12, 98, 45. So i am asking what to doif i want to keep zeros there.

Comment: I see. In this case, you need to convert numbers to strings.